# How to add saml: XML prefix when creating LightSAML IDP response

Tags: laravel, saml, saml-2.0

When generating a response, LightSAML IDP samples show it generates Attributes as mapping rules in the URL format:

```
<AttributeStatement>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
        <AttributeValue>email@example.com</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</AttributeStatement>
```

Is there a way to tell LightSAML to generate Attributes as constructs in the generic format, like SimpleSAMLPHP does:

```
<saml:AttributeStatement>
    <saml:Attribute Name="mail" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">email@example.com</saml:AttributeValue>
    </saml:Attribute>
</saml:AttributeStatement>
```

Apologies if I am using the incorrect terminology in my above question. Still learning SAML.

Comment: Extending Model/Assetion/AttributeStatement.php with a new serialize method that changes `$this->createElement('AttributeStatement'` to `$this->createElement('saml:AttributeStatement'` appears to do the trick. Is there an easier way without extending the class?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?